# How to enforce Functional Programming on Scala

Tags: scala

I'm starting to learn Functional Programming and would like to do so with Scala, not Haskell or Lisp.

But some people claim that learning Scala as the first functional language slows down your learning of Functional Programming, because Scala allows you to program both ways, and one tends to program the procedural way when confronted with a hard problem.

How can i **make sure** that 'm programming in a purely functional way? Maybe, due to not being able to properly distinguish both styles, I'll inadvertently program procedurally).

I know, for example, that I should only use vals and not vars.

Comment: Not related to the question, but if you want some good books, read in this specific order: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Comprehensive-Step-Step/dp/0981531644 → http://manning.com/suereth/ → http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/

Comment: Oh, and there's wart remover by Brian McKenna: https://github.com/pufuwozu/wartremover

Comment: "Scala is a gateway drug to Haskell" http://stackoverflow.com/a/7594599/367649

Comment: Purchase this book http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The other answers have made some good points, but for an attempt to quickly get down some guidelines, here's how I'd start:

Firstly, some things to completely avoid:

- Don't use the `var` keyword.
- Don't use the `while` keyword.
- Don't use anything in the `scala.collection.mutable` package.
- Don't use the `asInstanceOf` method.
- Don't use `null`. If you ever come across `null` (in someone else's code), immediately wrap it in a more appropriate datatype (usually `Option` will do nicely).

Then, a couple of things to generally avoid:

- Be wary of calling anything with a return type of `Unit`. A function with a return type of `Unit` is either doing nothing, or acting only by side-effects. In some cases you won't be able to avoid this (IO being the obvious one), but where you see it elsewhere it's probably a sign of impurity.
- Be wary of calling into Java libraries - they are typically not designed with functional programming in mind, and will often require you to abandon the functional approach.

Once you've avoided these things, what can you do to move your code to being more functional?

- When you're performing direct recursion, look for opportunities to generalise it through the use of higher order combinators. `fold` is likely your biggest candidate here - most operations on lists can be implemented in terms of a suitable `fold`.
- When you see destructuring operations on a data structure (typically through pattern matching), consider whether instead you can lift the computation into the structure and avoid destructuring it. An obvious example is the following code snippet:

  ```
  foo match {
    case Some(x) => Some(x + 2)
    case None => None
  }
  ```

  can be replaced with:

  ```
  foo map ( _ + 2 )
  ```

Comment: Wrapping `null` to a Option may lead to a cargo cult. I don't think you have to follow this rule blindly: sometimes code is slightly messed up with the use of *local* Options, where `if` use would be enough.

Comment: It's a fair point. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it in general, but for the author's specific case - making certain that they're writing in a purely functional way - I'd say it's a reasonable approach to just remove `null` entirely from the things they have to deal with.

Answer (score 11):

I dare say that your goal is already misleading:

> I'm starting to learn Function Programming, and I really wanna learn
>   Scala, not Haskell or Lisp.

If you are really interested in learning *concepts* of function programming, then why not use a language such as Haskell that (more or less) does not allow you to use procedural or object-oriented concepts? In the end, the language is "just" a tool that helps you learning concepts of FP, you could just as well read loads of papers about FP. At least theoretically, I think it is usually easier to learn concepts of computer science with concrete tools at hand.

On the other hand, if you are interested in learning the *language* Scala, then why not use all features that it offers, regardless of whether they stem from the FP or the OO world?

In order to conclude with a somewhat practical advise: You could search for FP tutorials that use Scala or for blog entries etc. that describe how to realise certain FP-concepts in Scala and try to follow them. This way, it is less likely that you make use of non-FP concepts.

Answer (score 8):

You don't buy a Ferarri to deliver furniture. Scala's fundamental strength is the fact that in your words, it goes both ways:). Whether or not you are programming in a functional style is decided by the techniques you use.

The best thing you can do is thoroughly review fundamental concepts of functional programming and seek the appropriate Scala implementation of the respective concepts. But if you want to program purely functional style, then go for Haskell, Lisp, Erlang, OCaml, or whatever other purely functional dialect.

**Functional programming**

[Introduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_programming)

[Functional thinking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ft20/)

**Scala**

If you want to learn Scala, then make sure to include both OO and FP in your learning curve. Lambda expressions + OO concepts + syntactic sugar made possible by IMHO the most advanced compiler on the face of the planet lead to something quite amazing. Take advantage of it!

Comment: I would say that most Lisps and Erlang are **not pure** functional.

Comment: You don't buy a Ferarri to deliver furniture.

Answer (score 2):

I think learning is non linear process, it helps to see lots of ways of doing the same thing, also be opportunistic and use any learning resources that are available for you. For example Martin Odersky the creator of Scala offers a free course called "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" https://class.coursera.org/progfun-002/class/index there are some very high quality video lectures, and some really good assignments where the automated grader will tell you that your code is not functional enough and you loose style points because you are using `var` instead of `val`

I think the thing you want to focus on is learning the Functional Programming Paradigm and for me learning a paradigm is about learning what types of problems are easy to solve in one paradigm and are hard to solve in another paradigm. Focus on the paradigm and I think you will find that learning both about Haskell and Scala will teach you the functional paradigm faster, because you will be able to ask the question what are the common features between Scala and Haskell, what are the differences .... etc

Answer (score 1):

`I know, for example, that I should only use vals and not vars.`

That's already a good start, other non-so-functional things to avoid are mutable collections and loops.

Have a look at immutable collections and recursion instead.

Of course, once you are familiar with the functional concepts, there might also be good reasons to use scala's non-functional features.